# React native : How to get city state and country using pincode number?

Tags: react-native

I have register page, in this there is one field which is pincode, what to do I have get country ,city and state using pincode number how to do this. I not found satisfied answer. Is there is third party library available? In react native.

Comment: update your question with code that you tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you can use google map apis for this to find anything you want, you can choose your desired sdk or api from following links
https://developers.google.com/maps and
https://developers.google.com/maps/apis-by-platform

Comment: Actually I couldn't get it what I want when user enter pincode using this pincode how to get couny  city and state? I am new in react native can you pls explain more...